# Sencha touch 2 model association saving incorrect data to store

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Please refer to the following fiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#xXQlp
Be sure to have your console open to see the output that shows the incorrect data.

Here you can see I'm creating 2 Student models, each of which have a list of 0+ Award models.  Dave has been given 2 rather nice awards - unsurprisingly :) - whereas Chaz has added 2 not-so-great awards.  The problem is that the logging shows that infact Chaz ends up with 4 awards (the 2 good ones, as well as the 2 bad ones).

This fiddle is a severe boiling down of a much larger app, but I have isolated this as the origin of a huge problem I've been having - I've even found a 'fix' for it.  If you uncomment lines 55 and 56 from the fiddle and run it again (be sure to clear your localstorage!), you will see that Chaz only has to 2 awards that he should.

For reasons that I hope are obvious, this is not a fix I'm happy with.  There has to be something else I'm doing wrong with the association to cause Chaz to get all 4 awards.
 ... surely?

Cheers!

UPDATE: Answer below accepted, removing autoLoad:true fixes the problem.  I want autoLoad however, so I implemented the following in the init of the Student model:

```
for (var i=0, l=this.associations.all.length; i<l; i++) {
    var assoc = this.associations.all[i];
    if (assoc._type == "hasmany") {
        var assocName = assoc._name;
        var getterName = 'get' + assocName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + assocName.slice(1);
        this[getterName] = function(assocName) {
            var self = this;
            return function() {
                var store = self[assocName]();
                if (!store.isLoaded()) {
                    store.load();
                }
                return store;
            }
        }.call(this, assocName)
    }
}
```

This adds a getter for each hasMany association that the student has, and ensures that the store for that association is loaded before returning it.  ie I can now access student1's awards with student1.getAwards() rather than student1.awards(), and know that the awards will have been loaded, this will automatically work for any other hasMany associations I add to the model.

I hope this is helpful to some readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not autoloading the awards will resolve this, remove the `autoload: true` on the students >> awards hasMany association. I don't fully understand why autoloading the awards breaks things though, but this forum thread suggests it's a bug: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?195371-autloaded-associations-don-t-properly-filter-data-from-a-JSON-proxy

Your example working: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#xXQlp#S3Af0

Comment: Thanks for finding that, it fixed the problem, although not having autoload is an annoyance, so I made the work around that I've added to my question.  Cheers.